# Make Complete Selection to show more items

Tags: front-end, customization, autocomplete

The Complete Selection function only shows 5 suggestions with others collapsed.
[image]

Is there a way not to collapse other items when I press ctrl-k?

Comment: Does this work for you: `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 CodeAssistOptions -> {"MaxContextMatches" -> 15,  "MaxGlobalMatches" -> 10}]`? Default values are 5 for both suboptions. You can alternatively use `$FrontEnd` instead of `$FrontEndSession`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of items in the drop-down menu seems to be controlled by the suboption `"MaxGlobalMatches"` of the option `CodeAssistOptions`. The latter can be set at the `EvaluationNotebook[]`, `$FrontEndSession` or `$FrontEnd` levels. The default value of the suboption is `5`.

```
Options[$FrontEndSession, CodeAssistOptions]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can change the value of this suboption to a higher value using `SetOptions`:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, CodeAssistOptions -> {"MaxGlobalMatches" -> 15}]
```

to get

[image: Mathematica graphics][image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: Couldn't figure out what the suboption `"MaxContextMatches"` does.

**Update:** For completeness, @andre's comment regarding `"MaxContextMatches"`

> `"MaxContextMatches"` certainly refers to the matches that hit the symbols that the user most commonly uses (a new feature introduce in Mma 9). See the first 4 minutes of [this video](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=313&v=431). At time=3m15, the talker use the expression "[symbols]... more frequently used in context than system symbols"

Comment: "MaxContextMatches" certainly refers to the matches thats hit the symbols that the user most commonly uses (a new feature introduce in Mma 9). See the first 4 minutes of [this video](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=313&v=431). At time=3m15, the talker use the expression "[symbols]... more frequently used in context than system symbols"

Comment: @andre, thank you.